# Maximum and minimum numbers in the list

Tags: racket

I am using DrRacket.

How can I write a function for the difference between the maximum and minimum number in the list using accumulators and mutually recursive functions.

For instance, (list 10 2 3 -5 4 1 -6)) 9). The list has at least one element in the list.

Do I need two accumulators?

Answer (score 0):

**Version 1**: An accumulator based solution that's mutually recursive. Since the input list is assumed to be non-empty, we start of with the first element being max and min. As we go through the list, we pick new max and mins by comparing the current element with the accumulators.

```
#lang racket

; [NEList-of Number] -> Number
(define (max-min-diff.v1 nelst)
  (max-min-diff/t.v1 (rest nelst) (first nelst) (first nelst)))

; [List-of Number] -> Number
(define (max-min-diff/t.v1 l max min)
  (cond [(empty? l) (- max min)]
        [else (get-new-max-min (rest l) (first l) max min)]))

; [List-of Number] Number Number Number -> Number
(define (get-new-max-min rst fst max min)
  (max-min-diff/t.v1 rst
                  (if (> fst max) fst max)
                  (if (< fst min) fst min)))


(max-min-diff.v1 '(0 33 2 32 4 8 3 3 5))
; => 33

(max-min-diff.v1'(1 3 9 4 7 2 2 5 11))
; => 10
```

**Version 2**: An accumulator based solution that's not mutually recursive. More abstract because we pass the comparators to a generic helper.

```
; [NEList-of Number] -> Number
(define (max-min-diff.v2 nelst)
  (max-min-diff/t.v2 (rest nelst) (first nelst) (first nelst)))

; [List-of Number] -> Number
(define (max-min-diff/t.v2 l max min)
  (cond [(empty? l) (- max min)]
        [else (max-min-diff/t.v2 (rest l)
                                (f-if (first l) max >)
                                (f-if (first l) min <))]))

; X X [X X -> Boolean] -> X
(define (f-if n1 n2 func)
  (if (func n1 n2) n1 n2))



(max-min-diff.v2 (list 0 33 2 32 4 8 3 3 5))
; => 33

(max-min-diff.v2 (list 1 3 9 4 7 2 2 5 11))
; => 10
```

**Version 3**: Small version. No explicit recursion.

```
(define (max-min-diff.v3 nelst)
  (- (apply max nelst) (apply min nelst)))

(max-min-diff.v3 (list 0 33 2 32 4 8 3 3 5))
; => 33

(max-min-diff.v3 (list 1 3 9 4 7 2 2 5 11))
; => 10
```